# Executing one stored procedure in another given the parameters of the the first one

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure A which takes 3 parameters: Two dates (from and to) and a table of int values (places).

Then, I have another stored procedure B which takes 2 parameters: date and int (a place).

What I need is to run the stored procedure B for all the dates between 'from' and 'to' and places which come as parameters to A inside of the stored procedure A and use the results there (in A)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Declare a table variable. Insert into @TableVar exec storedprocb param1 param 2.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How to make it so that the stored procedure B runs for all the places and for all the dates and have all the intermediate results put together?

Comment: It sounds like you could use a while loop with a union statement to accomplish what you're trying to do. I suspect that whatever it is that you're trying to accomplish could be done much more easily, and at significantly less cost to your server, by using a join statement though. Please post the code of these two stored procs and some sample output so we can help you more.

Comment: You are right. I wanted to avoid changing the stored procures' inputs but I ended up doing that and using JOIN instead. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
[Declare your fields here]
);

INSERT INTO @Table
EXEC YourStoredProc @InnerParam1 = @OuterParam1, @InnerParam2 = @OuterParam2;
```

That said, passing two of three parameters in a function through to another function feels wrong to me, but it should get the job done at the very least.